# Ubuntu 12.04 recovery mode root shell has no internet connection

Tags: networking, command-line, recovery-mode

I'm debugging some things on my computer and I boot into recovery mode from the grub menu. Then it gives me a bunch of options on what to do next, and I select the one that drops it to a root shell. However, apt-get complains about not being able to resolve hosts whenever I try to install anything. I'm assuming this is because it is not connected to the internet. How can I enable the internet connection from the root shell?

Answer (score 11):

Plug it in to the router with an Ethernet cable and run the `dhclient eth0` command.

Comment: An additional comment: `dhclient` configures a network interface (in this case `eth0`) -- "The Internet Software Consortium DHCP Client, dhclient, provides a means for configuring one or more network interfaces using the Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol, BOOTP protocol, or if these protocols fail, by statically assigning an address."